# Der Unterschied zwischen »umgeben von« und »umringt von«

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice, verb

> Ich stelle mir vor, dass wir einer dieser Sterne sind, **von den anderen umgeben**, und jeder dieser Sterne hat sein eigenes Sonnensystem.
>
> Ich stelle mir vor, dass wir einer dieser Sterne sind, **von den anderen umringt**, und jeder dieser Sterne hat sein eigenes Sonnensystem.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den zwei Ausdrücken und kann man die beiden in diesem Kontext verwenden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich stimme Jan zu, dass der Wortstamm *Ring* den Ausschlag gibt. Zwei weitere Aspekte, die mir wichtig scheinen:

- Ein Ring ist lückenlos, es muss also schon recht gedrängt zugehen, wie  beim Saturnring; die paar Stäubchen im Nichts, die andere Sterne darstellen, reichen dazu nicht aus.
- Ein Ring befindet sich hauptsächlich in einer Ebene. Das passt auf Menschenmassen, die alle auf derselben Ebene, nämlich dem Boden stehen, würde aber bei einer umgebenden Kugel oder beispielsweise einem Fahrzeug gar nicht passen (obwohl hier die Lückenlosigkeit erfüllt wäre). Bei anderen Sternen, die in alle möglichen nicht nur Himmels- sondern Raumrichtungen verstreut sind, passt auch das nicht.

Kurzum: Null von zwei Punkten, *umringen* ist ausgeschieden.

Answer (score 6):

*Umringen* enthält den Wortstamm *Ring.* Deswegen klingt es so, als existiere ein mehr oder weniger wohlgeformter Ring um das Zentralelement. *Umgeben* heißt jedoch nur, dass die umgebenden Gegenstände/Personen in alle Richtungen verteilt sind; kreisförmig wird nicht impliziert. Beispiele:

- > Die Sonne ist von Planeten umgeben.

  *Umringt* wäre falsch, weil die Planeten deutlich unterschiedliche Abstände zur Sonne haben, und es nur mit sehr viel Glück und Zufall etwas Ähnliches wie einen Ring ergäbe. *Umgeben* klingt zwar auch nicht ideal, aber wenn man sich die Weite des Alls vorstellt, und wie nah die Planeten dann doch der Sonne kommen, wird es akzeptabel.
- > Von Schaulustigen umgeben …
  >   Von Schaulustigen umringt …

  Hier könnte man auch *umringt* schreiben, denn üblicherweise drängen sich Schaulustige so nah an das zu Beschauende heran, dass dabei näherungsweise ein Kreis entsteht.
- > Eine Uhr besteht üblicherweise aus einer Achse, an der mindestens ein Zeiger hängt, und die von Ziffern umringt/umgeben ist.

  Auch hier: Es ist ein Kreis, also ein Ring, also ist beides möglich.
- > Der Minister ist von klangvollen Namen umgeben.

  Hier ist *umringt* zwar auch möglich, würde aber viel stärker die Gleichwertigkeit unterstellen, als es *umgeben* tut. Wer sich gerne mit namhaften Leuten umgibt, sorgt doch meistens dafür, dass nichts die Sicht auf einen selbst in der Mitte dieser Leute verstellt. Wer von namhaften Leuten umringt ist, könnte viel eher verdeckt sein.

Im Großen und Ganzen würde ich in deinem Beispiel lieber *umgeben* wählen. Das *Umringen* würde zu deutlich hervorheben, dass sich ein Ring der anderen um die Mitte bildet. Die nachfolgenden eigenen Sonnensysteme erwecken aber den Eindruck, dass jeder Stern für sich alleine steht, und die anderen ihn nur zufällig umgeben.

Comment: +1 für den Aspekt der Gleichwertigkeit

Comment: Insbesondere beim Beispiel mit den Schaulustigen stellen sich für mich unterschiedliche Gefühle ein: *umgeben* ist neutral bis positiv, z. B. bei einem Straßenkünstler, der von zahlreichen Schaulustigen/Zuschauern umgeben sein kann. *umringt* ist für mich eher negativ besetzt. Ein von Zuschauern umringter Straßenkünstler wäre in Bedrängnis und könnte sich nicht mehr frei bewegen.

Comment: @Raketenolli Das klingt wie eine Basis für eine Antwort ;)